# How to loop all the cell in the first tr of tbody with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm tried to loop all the cell in the first row in tbody table, but there is some problem with select the cell. Below my code:

```
$(".datatable_footer_fixed").prepend('<div class="new-foot"></div>');
var cells = document.getElementById('table').rows[0].cells.length;
var index;
for(index= 0; index< cells ; index++){
    cell = $("#table tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq("+index+")");
    if(index == 0 || index == cells-1){
        css = parseInt($(cell).css("width"));
    }else{
        css = parseInt($(cell).css("width")) + 16 + 23;
    }
    $(".new-foot").append("<div style=\"width:"+css+"px;height:20px display:inline-block;\"></div>");
}
```

The variable "cell" is empty, so var "css" is NaN and the div append have width: 0px.

How to fix it?

**EDIT:**

Now the script works, the problem was that the table was generate with the plugin Datatables.js of JQuery, and after the initialization of table i do the code but cannot find the content of the tr. I add a timeout of 3000ms and now it work. I fixed the code with the :nth-child() and .each() function. 
Thanks all for the help.

Comment: The issue is because you're missing a `;` between the inline styles. If you fix this it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/89athLby/2/. I'm voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can not post the HTML, i cannot have permissions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jQuery you can try this

```
jQuery('#table tr:first-child td').each(function(index){

   cell = jQuery(this);
if(index == 0 || index == (jQuery('#table tr:first-child td').length - 1)){
    css = parseInt(cell.css("width"));
}else{
    css = parseInt(cell.css("width")) + 16 + 23;
}

 $(".new-foot").append("<div style=\"width:"+css+"px;height:20px display:inline-block;\"></div>");

})
```

Comment: Why would changing a `for` loop to a `$.each()` loop make any difference?

Comment: `$.each()` is the jQuery way to perform a vanilla javascript `for.`  i Used $.each() because is easiest to write the right selector

Comment: Yes. My point is that it affects nothing. The problem is a typo in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child(n)` as the selector instead of using `eq`.

Note that `:eq` is a jQuery extension to selectors. For better performance you should use the native CSS `:nth-child()` syntax instead, i.e. `#table tr:nth-child(1)`, but note that this uses numbers starting from 1 instead of 0.

Your code would then be:

```
$(".datatable_footer_fixed").prepend('<div class="new-foot"></div>');
var cells = document.getElementById('table').rows[0].cells.length;
var index;
for(index= 1; index<= cells ; index++){
    cell = $("#table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child("+index+")");
    if(index == 1 || index == cells){
        css = parseInt($(cell).css("width"));
    }else{
        css = parseInt($(cell).css("width")) + 16 + 23;
    }
    $(".new-foot").append("<div style=\"width:"+css+"px;height:20px display:inline-block;\"></div>");
}
```

Comment: Note that OPs code already works. They are just missing a `;` in the style attribute

Comment: I see, still it could be that eq() doesnt work (depending on jquery version), so I think using nth-child is anyways better.

Comment: [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) has been available since jQuery 1.0. `:nth-child` and `eq()` do different things, so they are not directly interchangeable.

Comment: Well given 1.0 was the first public release in 2006, I'm guessing it's not an issue